# Check if a value has been updated on a html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following two forms. Is there a way of detecting when the value of the forms changes, preferably logging the value before and after, and if so what function actually changes the value.

```
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="billing_state">[CustomerInfo_state]</label>
  <select id="billing_state" onchange="check_address('billing');" name="billing_state" tabindex="9" class="txtBoxStyle">
  </select>
  <!--START: req_billing_state--> 
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
  <!--END: req_billing_state-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="chkField">
  <label for="billing_zip">[CustomerInfo_zip]</label>
  <input name="billing_zip" maxlength="15" type="text" id="billing_zip" value="[billing_zip]" size="10" tabindex="10" class="txtBoxStyle" onchange="clearContent(this);check_address('billing');" />
  <!--START: req_billing_zip--> 
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" /> 
  <!--END: req_billing_zip-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is an oninput attribute for html inputs.

Comment: `onchange` is the way, and you are already using it

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The zip is having a value from a shipping zip being set in it, i'm wanting to figure out why and what's setting it.

Comment: You want to know how the options in the select are loading?

Comment: Yea, the value is the same as another zip's value so somewhere there's a function that's going "billing_zip = shipping_zip", i'm not sure where in the code it is being printed (intern dealing with my first code base that isn't commented).

Comment: Search the code for references to `billing_zip`? Most IDEs have a way of doing that across a project.